# maven - how to compile code to jar file and not .class

Tags: java, maven, groovy, maven-jar-plugin

I am trying to build a groovy project using maven. My packaging type is war file. Maven is building the project and putting all dependent libraries in WEB-INF/lib folder but it is compiling all code into class files and putting it into WEB-INF/classes folder. Is there a way I can tell maven to build jar file for my project also and put it into WEB-INF/lib folder.

My pom.xml looks like this :

```
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>ExampleProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>My Example Project</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>

...
...
...
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/groovy</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.groovy</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/groovy</source>
                            <source>src/main/resources</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/test/groovy</source>
                            <source>src/test/resources</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>master</finalName>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

In these scenarios the usual approach is to you separate your library code in a different module that will be a dependency from your war module. For this suggestion you can see also [how to generate jar and war both in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190272/how-to-generate-jar-and-war-both-in-project) .

However if you still prefer to go with the solution you mention, you can do it with the following configuration in your pom

```
<configuration>
  ..
  <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
  <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
</configuration>
```

(see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html, and [how to use class file from another war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188495/how-to-use-class-file-from-another-war/10189767#10189767))