# How can I use classes from other project with maven? (ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError is thrown)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two Vaadin projects (I will name them A and B). Both are using Maven for resolving the dependencies and are in the same workspace. I'm working with Eclipse and I'm using the m2e-plugin. I want to use some classes of B in project A. In Eclipse I can instatiate them without errors/warnings but when I try to run A I get a `ClassNotFoundException` and a `NoClassDefFoundError` caused by instatiating a class of B.

The `.class` files of A are located in `...\workspace\A\target\classes` and the for project B they are in `...\workspace\B\target\classes`. 
I've been trying to solve this problem but I didn't find a solution.
What I tried so far:

- Configure build path -> Libaries -> add Class Folder -> B\target
- Configure build path -> Libaries -> add External Class Folder -> B\target
- Configure build path -> Projects -> add -> B

I think adding the project is necessary because when I remove it, Eclipse gives me error messages when I try to use the classes from B in A

I don't have any idea what else to do. Maybe I have to configure my `pom.xml` file but I don't know what I must do there.

Edit:
In pom.xml of project B:

```
<groupId>de.qufis</groupId>
<artifactId>CentwertApp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>CentwertApp</name>
```

In pom.xml of project A:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.qufis</groupId>
        <artifactId>CentwertApp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I did clean compile for project B with maven build.
Then I tried to do the same with project A but then I get error message:
Could not find artifact de.qufis:CentwertApp:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in vaadin-addons (http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons)

When I run the Application normally I still get the ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefError.

Edit 2:
I have added

```
<scope>compile</scope>
```

When I run Maven build (clean compile), part of my building process looks like this:

[INFO] Building centwertAdmin 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[WARNING] The POM for de.qufis:CentwertApp:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

Then there is the errormessage:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project centwertAdmin: Could not resolve dependencies for project de.qufis:centwertAdmin:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find de.qufis:CentwertApp:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vaadin-addons has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: can u try to remove <packaging>war</packaging> from B? plus, do u have B in the dependencies of A?

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188495/how-to-use-class-file-from-another-war/43338653#43338653

Answer (score 6, accepted):

can u try to remove `<packaging>war</packaging>` from B? Maven's default packaging is `jar`, and this is what you need for B.

Plus, add B to the `dependencies` of A.

- Build B project. use `mvn clean install`, that would install B's
  JAR+POM in your local repository (.m2).
- Verify it is there... Then
  Maven will be able to find it, so you will not get the error "Could
  not find artifact de.qufis:CentwertApp"
- Build A.

Usually, dependencies are of type JAR. If B **must** be a WAR, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769586/maven-war-dependency).

Comment: I stillt get the same mistake when I try to do Maven build (clean compile) in porject A.
I get this warning:
`[WARNING] The POM for de.qufis:CentwertApp:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available`.
CentwertApp is project B.
I allready added B to the dependecies of A

Comment: edited the answer... is it working now? i saw that you marked @Tunaki's answer as "accepted"

Comment: Do i have to build it as a jar file? or do i just have to build it and verify that it is in my local repository. And i just tried to mark @Tunaki's answer as useful but it didnt work so i accepted it ;)

Comment: yes. build it as a jar and follow the steps i mentioned. let me know if it helps.

Comment: I did maven build (clean package) for project B. So I got a jar file which i copied into .m2 folder. But when i do maven build (clean compile) for project A i still get the message that the pom.xml for project B is missing.

Comment: i bet you did not copy it to the correct place... rather than mvn build, try to run mvn install. that will let maven copy the JAR+POM to the correct place in your local repo (.m2).