# How to utliize Custom Converter in jOOQ using Maven configuration?

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, maven, jooq

I'm having issue with setting **pom.xml** file in my Maven project which is using [vertx-jooq](https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/tree/master/vertx-jooq-classic-reactive) library (combo of **vertx** and **jOOQ** library).

My main project is let's say **project A (vertx-my-project)** and I need reference **project B** ([vertx-jooq-generate](https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/tree/master/vertx-jooq-generate)). I've referenced project B inside of project A's ***pom.xml*** file in **dependencies** section:

```
<dependencies>
 <!-- ...other necessary dependencies in Project A -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.jklingsporn</groupId>
    <!-- artifactId is project B's artifactId -->
    <artifactId>vertx-jooq-generate</artifactId>  
    <version>5.1.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

...and also I've referenced it (Project B) in Eclipse by checking it in ***Project References*** section of Project's Properties window.
BTW, I'm using this one [ClassicReactiveVertxGenerator](https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/blob/master/vertx-jooq-generate/src/main/java/io/github/jklingsporn/vertx/jooq/generate/classic/ClassicReactiveVertxGenerator.java) as default code generator for my project.

I've created custom converter (like in [this](https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/blob/master/vertx-jooq-generate/src/test/java/io/github/jklingsporn/vertx/jooq/generate/custom/CustomVertxGenerator.java) example and let's call it **CustomGenerator**)  which  is used to convert **to/from String to/from** `java.time.LocalDateTime` type in order to be able to work with **Timestamp** field type because Vert.x `JsonObject` does NOT have getter/setter methods for Timestamp type implemented. I did this by adding another project as a dependency in my original project and by changing (to be more precise **adding**) 2 methods in class which is used as **generator class**.

Also, I did a research on how to properly utilize CustomGenerator in pom.xml file but no luck. So my question is how can I use **my CustomGenerator** and/or can someone please point out what should I do/look for?
Thank you in advance.

**PS.** I'm using **jooq-codegen-maven 3.13.1** version in Maven project.

Comment: There could be many many reasons why *something* went wrong in your approaches, but we weren't there when it happened. Please check out this useful resource to help us help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @LukasEder: Hi Lukas, thank you showing interest in this issue. I've updated my question and if anything else is needed to provide suggestion on solving it please let me know.

Comment: @LukasEder I've managed to solve it by doing steps given in my answer. If you have any suggestion on solving this kind of problem or similar ones please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated my question to make it more clear what I actually did and want to achieve.

After couple of hours of doing some more experimenting I've managed to reach a solution by doing:
**1)** Edit **already** used CustomGenerator [ClassicReactiveVertxGenerator](https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/blob/master/vertx-jooq-generate/src/main/java/io/github/jklingsporn/vertx/jooq/generate/classic/ClassicReactiveVertxGenerator.java) already created in Project B (vertx-jooq-generate) and add it 2 necessary methods (actually [these](https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/blob/master/vertx-jooq-generate/src/test/java/io/github/jklingsporn/vertx/jooq/generate/custom/CustomVertxGenerator.java) 2) for conversion.
**2)** Run `mvn clean install` on Project B and then on Project A

That solved issue. I've managed to do this by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33904904/6805866) answer.